# Need for Rails plugin management tools?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I've been searching for a while, and I can't find any modern rails plugin management tools.  I found several gem management tools (such as bundler and isolate), but no plugin management tools.  The closest thing to that I found was piston, and that's not exactly what I was looking for was it was for plugin svn:externals management.  Our plugins are not using svn:externals.  Some can be used as gems, and managed by bundler, but not all plugins are offered by their developers in that form.

They can always be managed by hand, of course, but I'd rather have a tool to keep them current, etc., that works for plugins like isolate or bundler work for gems.

If others could use this I'll see if I can get supervisor approval to work on such and contribute it, assuming also there's not a good or even fair solution out there that I'm missing.

Cheers,
Craig

Comment: Piston is a good solution, but its creator is the first to admit that plugins are bound to disappear and piston will soon be a thing of the past.

Comment: Gems are vastly superior to plugins for exactly this reason. Maybe you can help the authors of plugins to publish them as gems? Gem authoring is extremely easy, and (especially in Rails 3) gems can do everything that plugins can do.

Answer (score 0):

I use `git submodules` for that.

But, indeed in Rails 3, it is more natural to package each plugin as a gem, and i think it is the preferred way, especially for the reasons you mention.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  So you mean import the plugin code and put it in my own git repo?   How'd you keep it in sync with the remomte (e.g., origin/master, or trunk for SVN based plugins).